# Python : Move a block a cells in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting

I encountered formatting issue that needed a column shift that can be illustrated by something like this :

```
df =                     
    A    B    C    D    E
0    foo    spam    egg    0    0
1    bar    egg    1    0.84    NaN
2    bar    egg    2    0.91    NaN
3    foo    spam    egg    3    0.14
4    foo    spam    egg    4    -0.76
```

to this :

```
    df =                    
    A    B    C    D    E
0    foo    spam    egg    0    0.00
1    bar    spam    egg    1    0.84
2    bar    spam    egg    2    0.91
3    foo    spam    egg    3    0.14
4    foo    spam    egg    4    -0.76
```

For which i made the following fix :

```
columnShift = df.columns[-3:]
indexes = [i for i,x in enumerate(df.B) if x =='egg']

for i in indexes:
    for c in np.arange(1,len(columnShift)):
        df.loc[i,columnShift[-c]] = df.loc[i,columnShift[-(c+1)]]
```

It is functionnal but it feels unelegant and takes quite a long time. 
I was thus wondering if there was better solution to apply to larger dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the original df is

```
df =                     
    A    B    C    D    E
0    foo    spam    egg    0    0
1    bar    egg    1    0.84    NaN
2    bar    egg    2    0.91    NaN
3    foo    spam    egg    3    0.14
4    foo    spam    egg    4    -0.76
```

The code below should do what you need:

```
new_cols = [cols[0], cols[-1]] + cols[1:-1].tolist()
part = df.iloc[1:3, :][new_cols]
df.iloc[1:3, :] = part.values
```

Comment: I had to change `cols[1:-1]` to `cols[1:-1].tolist()` in order for the solution to work.
Then is worked perfectly fine and was extremely faster.

Comment: Glad it worked out, I'll modify my answer as you commented, so that it would have better tolerance on different machines.